# Determining control flow of GCC

Tags: gcc, profiling, control-flow

I want to understand how GCC works, therefore would like to know which functions are executed in which sequence. For me, it is hard to understand it by only looking at the GCC source code.

Is there any tool to track the internal functions that are being called by GCC when compiling a c file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use debugger to execute gcc step-by-step, but gcc it is quite complicated piece of software.

Comment: Can you recommend any debugging tools that suit for this purpose?

Comment: Anything you like e.g. Eclipse cdt, it will give you nice UI. Don't forget - you have to build debug version of gcc.